# How to change format of returned list in web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm fairly new to WEB API so please forgive the ignorance. I'm trying to return a list of events that a specific user will be attending and nothing more. My code works but it returns more info than I need. This is what is returned when I call the API : [{"$id":"1","eventID":"1"},{"$id":"2","eventID":"2"}]

My controller code is as follows:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    List<GetEventAttend> events = null;
    events = db.userattends.Where(x => x.userID == id).Select(s => new GetEventAttend()
    { eventID = s.eventID }).ToList<GetEventAttend>();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, events);
}
```

This is the code for GetEventAttend:

```
public class GetEventAttend
{

    public string eventID { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way I can return in the format of {"1","2"}?

Comment: You have configured reference handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there but instead of selecting a new `GetEventAttend` you can just select the `eventID` fields and return those:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    var events = db.userattends.Where(x => x.userID == id).Select(s => s.eventID).ToList();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, events);
}
```

Is the `GetEventAttend` class really that small or is that just for demo purposes? If it is just a container for the web api result than you do not need that class, as the answer shows you.

EDIT: CodeCaster has a point. This answer will return an array of eventIds. This might suffice for now but in later stages you might want to return an array of events, even if they consist of just the identifier. Because now if you want to include additional information about the event you have to create a new api or introduce breaking changes.

In the original code you have probably configured reference handling, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#handling-circular-object-references) on how to disable that:

> ```
> var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
> json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = 
> Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
> ```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: That'll just select return a list of strings, which is bad for maintainability when you want to extend the response sometime.

Comment: @CodeCaster point taken, I took the liberty to elaborate on it in my answer.